# What lenses for a Nikon camera have both an AF motor and an aperture ring?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, slr, nikon-d5600

I have a Nikon FE10 35mm film SLR ***and*** a D5600 DSLR.

I want a wide focal length prime or mid range zoom (nothing longer than 120mm) to use on both cameras.

I need an aperture ring for the film SLR use, and I want Auto Focus ability with my D5600.

I have been going back and forth on AI AiS AFD AFS G N and everything in between, to the point of exhaustion. So now its time to simply ask for help and suggestions.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think the cheapest option would be to buy a used D7000 or similar.

Answer (score 2):

A full list of Nikon lenses which can auto-focus with the D5x00 line is available on Wikipedia at [List of Nikon F-mount lenses with integrated autofocus motor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nikon_F-mount_lenses_with_integrated_autofocus_motor).

The lenses with an aperture ring are those *without* a **G** in their designation.

So, for example, the first suitable lens in the list, under wide-angle primes, is the AF-S Nikkor 28mm f/1.4E ED.

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot have an E either, so the first one I find is the Nikon AF-S Nikkor 300mm f/4D IF-ED.

Answer (score 2):

Your question looks straightforward but it is not so easy, indeed !

[Ken Rockwell’s overview](https://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm) is quite exhaustive. Basically, AF-S and AF-I would be a good match for both your FE10 and your D5600. Most if not all AF-I are telezoom/telephoto. Furthermore, no AF-S with E, no AF-S with G of course would match your needs as they have no aperture ring. For instance, AF-S (“Silent motor”) can be with or without ring aperture. In the latest, G or E are added. Conversely, most AF-D have no internal motor. Autofocus can’t work with your D5600 without an internal motor. But some D lenses have silent motor inside! They are “D type AF-S”. That’s the kind of lens you will need. Yes, it is somewhat complicated, I agree.

This is confirmed by Nikon official pages about [FE10](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/film-cameras/fm10.html) (what works for FE10 will work for FM10 AFAIK) and [D5600](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?lang=en_GB&articleNo=000005532) lens compatibility (open on the D5600 page the xls file). It is confusing to state FE10 works with AF-S. It works with AF-S non-G and non-E !

The FE10 will require a full frame lens, so no DX lens for your requirements, only FX lens would be a match.

To summarize, you need an **FX lens which is D type with AF-S.**

When it comes to the lenses you want, the choice looks very limited and a little bit… awkward. Indeed, most of the AF-S and AF-I which are no G or E are Telephoto / Pro super Telephoto. So, I went through the whole list of Nikon lens to double check (again look at the xls file in reference above) and the 2 only lenses I could find were:

*AF-S Zoom-Nikkor 28-70mm f/2.8D IF-ED*

*AF-S Zoom-Nikkor 17-35mm f/2.8D IF-ED*

Both zooms used to be excellent at their time (pro zooms) but they are outpaced, whilst very solid and very heavy. You can still buy the 17-35 according to [Nikon official site](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-zoom-nikkor-17-35mm-f%252f2.8d-if-ed.html). And it is easy very easy to find the AF-S 28-70 D second hand, but usually quite expensive too. Again, both zooms are pro lenses.

To be honest, I understand the need to have the same lens for both bodies, but I am not totally convinced it is the best approach due to the limited and expensive choice you have. Well, at least you know what is possible.